# My loop is ending wrong, it's exceeding the limit I've given

Tags: java

I'm trying to resolve this problem: Given integer N. Print all the squares of natural numbers, not exceeding N, in ascending order.

For example, lets say N = 50, it prints =

```
1
4
9
16
25
36
49
```

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int N = sc.nextInt();
    int b = 0;

    while (N > b){
        b++;
        int m = b*b;
        System.out.println(m);
       if (N < m){
break;
}
```

With my code I'm getting

```
1
4
9
16
25
36
49
64
```

So, it's kinda working but it's exceeding my int N for some reason. Even though the condition states that if N < m, it should break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is to, break from loop if condition is met, else print the value. I have rearranged the code below by moving the print statement below the condition -

```
if (N < m){
break;
}
System.out.println(m);
```

Comment: Hahaha I tried the last code, i was very happy and then it did not work and I ohh:C, then I saw that it had been edited and now it works, thank you very much: D you saved me.

Comment: I made a mistake and then edited it out :D . Glad it worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is a bit off, you want `b + 1 <= Math.sqrt(N)`. Like,

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int N = sc.nextInt();
int b = 0;
while (b + 1 <= Math.sqrt(N)) {
    b++;
    System.out.println(b * b);
}
```

Comment: Hello, I still don't know Math, but thank you very much for your answer, I'll see it later;), I solved it with the other answer.

Comment: Ummm... `while ((b+1)*(b+1) <= N)` but whatever works for you.